# How to display htmlcontent string in web browser control in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have web browser control in which I am displaying Htmlcontent using javascript and NavigateToString() methods. It was working fine unless table tag was added at server from where I am getting the Htmlcontent. I have tried below code so far

```
string notifyJS = @"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
                            window.onload = function() {
                                var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                                for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
                                    links[i].onclick = function() {
                                        window.external.Notify(this.href);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        </script>";


        var htmlContent = string.Format("<html><head>{2}</head>" +
                                                 "<body style=\"margin:25px 25px 75px;padding:0px;background-color:{1};\" " +
                                                 "{0}</body></html>",
                                                 _selectedTab.HTML_CONTENT,
                                                 _selectedTab.TAB_BG_COLOR,
                                                 notifyJS);
        //var htmlContent = _selectedTab.HTML_CONTENT;

        HtmlContentView.NavigateToString(htmlContent);
        HtmlContentView.ScriptNotify += HtmlContentView_ScriptNotify;
        HtmlContentView.Navigating += HtmlContentView_Navigating;
        HtmlContentView.LoadCompleted += HtmlContentView_LoadCompleted;
    }

    void HtmlContentView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlContentView.InvokeScript("execScript", new string[] { "document.onselectstart=function(){return false;};document.ondragstart=function(){return false;}" });

    }

    void HtmlContentView_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    void HtmlContentView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
        {
            string href = e.Value.ToLower();
            if (href.StartsWith("mailto:"))
            {
                EmailComposeTask email = new EmailComposeTask();
                email.To = href.Replace("mailto:", string.Empty);
                email.Show();
            }
            else if (href.StartsWith("tel:"))
            {
                PhoneCallTask call = new PhoneCallTask();
                call.PhoneNumber = href.Replace("tel:", string.Empty);
                call.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                WebBrowserTask browserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
                browserTask.Uri = new Uri(e.Value);
                browserTask.Show();

            }
        }
    }
```

Please can anyone suggest why table tag is not properly recognized? I checked the same in Android and it was working absolutely fine.

Please anyone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known problem that NavigateToString() function for the web browser control in WP8 is not working normally. Try using CSS and DIVs instead, as there is no other solution at the moment.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Can you suggest some code which I can add in my code to achieve my requirements??

Comment: I do not know your context exactly, so I think just suggesting some code won't solve your issue. I think that your problem will be successfully solved if you replace your HTML table with another HTML content which will look more or less the same as the table looked. Try marking this question as answered if you think that it is, and place another question asking for help with that particular content if you want direct answers to your next question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution from this link
[Solution](http://w3facility.org/question/web-browser-does-not-show-web-pages-properly-in-windows-phone-8-application/)

and I have added meta tag as per their suggestion and its working great.

```
var htmlContent = string.Format("<html><head>{2}<meta name='viewport' content='inital-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' /></head>" +      
                                                 "<body style=\"background-color:{1};\"" +
                                                 "{0}</body></html>",
                                                 _selectedTab.HTML_CONTENT,
                                                 _selectedTab.TAB_BG_COLOR,
                                                 notifyJS);
        //var htmlContent = _selectedTab.HTML_CONTENT;

        HtmlContentView.NavigateToString(htmlContent);
```

Hope it helps some one.